# Why 400 Bad Request when creating TeamCity cloud profile?

Tags: amazon-ec2, teamcity

I'm trying to create a cloud profile to start an EC2 instance in TeamCity. But I get `Failed to connect to Amazon EC2. null (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: null)`  There is no any explanations about this. As you can see I have changed `serverURL` to `https://google.com`, but it produces the same error even when using the correct TeamCity server.

[image]
I checked outbound connections of the EC2 instance where TeamCity is deployed and it's fine. Also tried by changing the region.

Any thoughts?

Cheers!